# jQuery target data element in nested list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list which is structured something like this:

```
<ul  data-Id="2" class="listElement">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li>
    <ul data-Id="3" class="listElement" style="display: none">
        <li></li>
        <li>
            <ul data-Id="4" class="listElement" style="display: none">
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I need to be able target the ul element which is currently hidden, and do a `slidetoggle()` on it. This I have tried to do in jQuery, but it doesn't work so well:

```
var test = 3; //i need to declare it as a var, because i get this from another item 
$('.listElement').find('[data-Id="' + test + '"]').slideToggle("fast");
```

Nothing really happens and I can't seem to find what I'm missing here

Comment: Your code is working: https://jsfiddle.net/gdcak71y/. If it doesn't work for you check the console for errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, but please make sure dom elements has been already placed(ready) when your javascript code is run.
Or your javascript should be run on ready event of document hired.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var test = 3; //i need to declare it as a var, because i get this from another item 
    $('.listElement').find('[data-Id="' + test + '"]').slideToggle("slow");
});
```